# ORA-13029 - Invalid SRID in the SDO_GEOMETRY object

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I´m suddenly getting the following error:

```
ORA-13029 - Invalid SRID in the SDO_GEOMETRY object
```

When trying to update a table´s geometry using a trigger. The new geometry object has SRID set to 3009. The metadata of the table is set to SRID 3009 and all geometries in the table are set to SRID 3009, so it seems to me that the error should not come up?

Any suggestions on what more to look for would be helpful.

Comment: are you using Oracle 19c ??

Comment: Yes, the database was quite recently moved from 12c.

Answer (score 0):

It is reported that after migrating from 12c to 19c, 3D geometrys are reported as INVALID in 19c, but are evaluated as VALID in 12.2. Example:

12.2.0.1

```
SQL> select instance_name, version from v$instance;

INSTANCE_NAME    VERSION
---------------- -----------------
ORCL_12c         12.2.0.1.0

SQL> SELECT toid,
  2     t.geometry.SDO_SRID SRID,
  3     SUBSTR(t.geometry.SDO_GTYPE, 1, 1) DIM_COUNT,
  4     SUBSTR(t.geometry.SDO_GTYPE, 4, 1) GTYPE,
  5     SDO_GEOM.VALIDATE_GEOMETRY_WITH_CONTEXT(t.geometry, 0.05) VALIDATION_RES
  6  FROM test_geom t;

TOID                     LENGTH DIM_ GTYP VALIDATION_RES
-------------------- ---------- ---- ---- ---------------
testdata101               27700 3    3    TRUE
testdata201               27700 3    3    TRUE
testdata301               27700 3    3    TRUE
testdata401               27700 3    3    TRUE
testdata501               27700 3    3    TRUE
```

19c

```
SQL> select instance_name, version from v$instance;

INSTANCE_NAME    VERSION
---------------- -----------------
ORCL_19c         19.0.0.0.0

SQL> SELECT toid,
  2     t.geometry.SDO_SRID SRID,
  3     SUBSTR(t.geometry.SDO_GTYPE, 1, 1) DIM_COUNT,
  4     SUBSTR(t.geometry.SDO_GTYPE, 4, 1) GTYPE,
  5     SDO_GEOM.VALIDATE_GEOMETRY_WITH_CONTEXT(t.geometry, 0.05) VALIDATION_RES
  6  FROM test_geom t;

TOID                     LENGTH DIM_ GTYP VALIDATION_RES
-------------------- ---------- ---- ---- ---------------
testdata101               27700 3    3    13029
testdata201               27700 3    3    13029
testdata301               27700 3    3    13029
testdata401               27700 3    3    13029
testdata501               27700 3    3    13029
```

This behavior is due to an unpublished software defect. **Apply the latest Spatial MERGE patch.31022826 which fixes this issue.**

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer! Although all existing geometries are returned as valid when i tried the SQL-statement you provided. The new geometry in this case is 2d though. For example : 

MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 3009, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(187538.78, 6557957.025))

I did howerver experience the same error previously in another case with already existing 3D-geometries in a table, perhaps the information you provided can help solve that problem.

Comment: that was only an example. I know there are several bugs related with Spatial in 19c and geometries that were working without issues in 12c. You must apply the patch and contact Support  Most probable cause it is bug in Spatial

Comment: Ok. Thanks alot for the advice, will check it out.